# Make sure mobile user isn't sending fake date, time and timezone to the server

Tags: date, datetime, timezone, ntp

A mobile app has a check-in feature for the user to send a photo and observation and the app will append his location, date and time to the request, and send it to the server.

It is extremely important that this date and time is not faked by the user, or else the user will be able to be late at work but check-in with a fake "15 minutes ago".

The server is in USA, and the users are in many countries so there are different date and timezones, for that reason I *think* I can't use server date and time.

That check-in is visible in a website to users all around the world, but the check-in time must be the one from the user who made it.

#### Example

User checks-in at 5th July 13:45 in Mexico.
Website should show this date and time, **5th July 13:45**, even if it's visualized by someone in Japan.

### Problem

User checks-in at 6th July 09:37 in Brazil, but he fakes his mobile date and time settings to say it's 6th July 09:00 to pretend he's not late for work.

How can the sever know it's actually 6th July 09:37 and not 09:00, and show that correct date and time to whoever sees it anywhere in the world?

Keep in mind that user can also fake his timezone and GPS, still the server needs to get the *real* timezone to show real and not mislead information.

Comment: It’s not that bad, but the server needs to know the user’s time zone so it can make its own conversion. Next question is of course what happens if the user fakes his or her time zone…

Comment: @OleV.V. I already said in the question that I need a way to also get the real timezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is extremely important that this date and time is not faked by the user, or else the user will be able to be late at work but check-in with a fake "15 minutes ago".

This part is best handled by taking a UTC timestamp from the server when the request is received.

> The server is in USA, and the users are in many countries so there are different date and timezones, for that reason I think I can't use server date and time.

Time zone is irrelevant for this purpose.  Get the UTC time from the server, not the local time.  The local time of the server should not ever be used in your application code.

If you need to adjust it to a particular time zone, then you can collect that from the user in a variety of ways, or you could assign one permanently to the user by some administrator of your application.  Even if the time zone is wrong or faked, it won't affect the duration of time worked - because you captured that in UTC.

> Example
>   User checks-in at 5th July 13:45 in Mexico.
>   Website should show this date and time, 5th July 13:45, even if it's visualized by someone in Japan.

That's fine.  Save that the user is in Mexico (... actually, Mexico has several time zones, so you'll need to be more specific - use [an IANA time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)).  You can convert the UTC timestamp to Mexico time whenever you like - either when you recieve the timestamp (saving both UTC and Mexico time), or when you display it to the user (saving only UTC and converting to Mexico time at the time of display).  That the user is in Japan is also irrelevant to this scenario.

> Problem
>   User checks-in at 6th July 09:37 in Brazil, but he fakes his mobile date and time settings to say it's 6th July 09:00 to pretend he's not late for work.

That's not an issue if you capture the time in UTC at the server and make sure your server's clock is synchronized properly.

> Keep in mind that user can also fake his timezone and GPS, still the server needs to get the real timezone to show real and not mislead information.

Indeed.  You can't capture this information *from the user* in a way that can't be falsified.  However, you can avoid relying on this in your application code.  For pure duration calculation, just base everything on UTC.  For more complex things (like determining shift differentials or daily overtime working over midnight or at other peak local hours, etc.) then have *some other user* set the time zone that's applicable rather than collecting it.  For example, assuming these are employees, the employee's manager or HR department would assign a time zone to the employee's personnel record.

Of course, if the employee is traveling for their job, and local time rules apply differently in different time zones, then you have even more logic to think about how you capture such details.  (My experience tells me this is rare.)

Comment: Firstly, that's high quality information, thank you very much! Secondly, What's the difference between `UTC server time` and `server local time`?

Comment: Servers general track time in UTC.  Time zones are a layer on top of that. You didn't tell us anything about your language/platform on the server, so I can't give you the specific api.  But as an example, if it were C#/.NET you would call `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want to do. Your app relies on the mobile device's OS to get things like date, time, timezone and gps. While it's harder to fake gps data on out of the box OS's it's always going to be possible. What you really want is a "backdoor". A backdoor that will let you get to the user device's "real" information no matter how hard the user tries to hide it. If that were possible we wouldn't need/have hackers and government cyber security teams. Anyone who knew the backdoor could just find anyone else in the world.

You can only try to catch such abusers using  some of your own measures. You can check if the users time zone is changing. Or using an ip address from a different country since the last time he/she used the app. Or if you're really going to ask for gps permission, you can also see if that person's location over time doesn't make sense (E.g the user was in Canada but 3 hours later it looks like they're in China). Once you detect such possible abuse, you can flag the account for human review.

Comment: One other thing is that you can make every user select their country during signup. Then going forward you could use the server time to figure out the local time according to the user. Other options are to maybe check if the AUTO_TIME_ZONE flag is set (android api17+)

Comment: I'm already checking that flag but I couldn't get that information on iOS.

Comment: Note that the auto_time_zone flag also doesn't have any guarantee. The time is updated using a background service so I could possibly change my timezone, then re-enable auto_time_zone and then quickly, before the OS changes my timezone back, I can log into your app and check-in